# Qualtrics - Passing Response into Javascript for API Call

Tags: javascript, qualtrics

I have a survey in Qualtrics. In one question, the respondent provides an email address. I need to send that email address to a gift card provider (Giftbit) using their API. My code below is located in an "End of Survey Element" as a custom end of survey message.

I am trying to capture the respondent-provided email address as piped text (${q://QID6/ChoiceTextEntryValue}) in HTML, and then pass that value into JavaScript using the getEmailAddress function below. Then I assign that value as emailAddressText in the API call that follows.

Thanks in advance for your suggestions - I've tweaked the code a few dozen times and I'm out of ideas.

```
Thank you for completing the survey.

<span id="EmailAddress" style="display: none;">${q://QID6/ChoiceTextEntryValue}</span>

<script>

function getEmailAddress() {
   var emailAddressText=("EmailAddress").innerHTML;
}


var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

request.open('POST', 'https://testbedapp.giftbit.com/papi/v1/campaign');

request.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
request.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ACCESS_TOKEN');

request.onreadystatechange = function () {
  if (this.readyState === 4) {
    console.log('Status:', this.status);
    console.log('Headers:', this.getAllResponseHeaders());
    console.log('Body:', this.responseText);
  }
};

var body = {
  'message': 'Thanks for completing the survey.',
  'subject': ‘Here is your $50 gift card!',
  'contacts': [
    {
      'email': emailAddressText
    }
  ],
  'marketplace_gifts': [
    {
      'id': 1,
      'price_in_cents': 5000
    }
  ],
  'expiry': '2018-01-01',
  'id': 'clientProvidedGiftId_abc123'
}; 
request.send(JSON.stringify(body));

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You never call the getEmailAddress function and even if you did emailAddressText is local to that function (you don't return it).

A better way would be to just pipe the email address into the script where you want it (in place of the span tag and the getEmailAddress function):

```
  'contacts': [
    {
      'email': '${q://QID6/ChoiceTextEntryValue}'
    }
  ],
```

Also, you should add this as JavaScript, not part of the question with a script tag.